# Flutter-Filtrar objetos

Tags: flutter, dart, programación-móvil, jsonobject, where

estoy leyendo una api,  necesito filtrar los **productos** que contengan en el subgrupo la palabra **fuertes**, pero no lo he logrado. Soy nueva en flutter y apenas conozco algunos metodos como where; este me trae el subgrupo, mas no el producto como en el siguien ejemplo.

"subgroup": {
"_id": "111122222",
"code": 12b,
"description": "FUERTES",
}

Esta es la estructura del json

"id": "11111111",
"code": 123,
"producto": "FRIJOLES",
"price": "33,480.00",
"subgroup": {
"_id": "111122222",
"code": 12b,
"description": "FUERTES",
},

Comment: Por favor, incluye lo que has intentado o investigado hasta el momento. También es posible que puedas buscar preguntas similares, he visto ya antes preguntas que te podrían ayudar con tu problema

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se me ocurre es que puedes hacer algo así:

```
  List<Map> filteredProducts = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++){
      
    if(products[i]["subgroup"].toString().toLowerCase().contains("fuertes")){
    filteredProducts.add(products[i]);
    }
  };
  return filteredProducts;  
}
```

Compruebas que el dentro del objeto "subgroup" esté la palabra "fuertes" y si es así pues lo va a agregando a la lista que regresa la función.

Al final es solo pasarle el array que te llega con los datos y la función se encarga de filtrar.

Comment: Muchas gracias!